# How to generate a QR code with templated data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, qr-code, mustache

I'm currently using Express, Mustache and QRCode.js.

Currently, when editing a product from the database, a mustache template is used and the /id is added to the end of the URL to specify which product ID will be edited. On this edit page, at the bottom, I was able to create a QR code with QRCode.js that links to the current page. It is to be downloaded and printed on to a sticker, which will go on a shelf. That way, users can scan the QR code with their phone and subtract from the product inventory.

However, I'd really like to add the {{product.productId}}, {{product.Manufacturer}} and {{product.product.Sku}} on the right of that downloadable QR code. That way, they can easily be downloaded and go straight to a printer, instead of having to drop them in an editing program to add the information manually. This is my first back-end product. Would someone give me a roadmap on how to accomplish it?

Here is my code:

```
<pre>

    <div class="generate">

    <div class="generate_qrcode" id="output"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="qrcode__span">Right click to download as a .png</div>

     <!-- <img class="QRCode" src="qrcode-encoding.png" /> -->
        <script>
            let qrcode = new QRCode("output", {
                text: window.location.href,
                width: 256,
                height: 256,
                colorDark : "#04243c",
                colorLight : "#FFFFFF",
                correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
            });
        </script>

    <!-- HTML/Product Edit Field (on same page as above code) -->


    <body class="product_edit">
            <h2 class="ep__h2">Edit Product</h2>
            <div class="ep">
            <form class="ep__form" 
    action="/product_edit/{{product.productId}}" method="POST" 
    autocomplete="off">
                <label for="productname" class="ep__label">Product Name: 
    </label>
                <input type="text" name="product_name" class="ep__input" 
    placeholder="Product Name" value="{{product.productName}}">
                <label for="manufacturer" class="ep__label">Manufacturer: 
    </label>
                <input type="text" name="product_manufacturer" 
    class="ep__input" placeholder="Manufacturer" value=" . 
    {{product.productManufacturer}}">
                <label for="product_size" class="ep__label">Size:</label>
                <input type="text" name="product_size" class="ep__input" 
    placeholder="Size" value="{{product.productSize}}">
                <label for="product_qty" class="ep__label">Quantity: 
    </label>
                <button type="button" class="ep__qtyminus" value="-" 
    name="product_qty" field="product_qty">-</button>
                <input type="number" name="product_qty" 
    class="ep__qtynumber" value="{{product.productQty}}">
                <button type="button" class="ep__qtyplus" value="+" 
    name="product_qty" field="product_qty">+</button>
                <label for="product_sku" class="ep__label--half">SKU: 
    </label>
                <label for="product_minimum" class="ep__label-- 
    half">Minimum:</label>
                <input type="text" name="product_sku" class="ep__input-- 
    half" placeholder="SKU" value="{{product.productSku}}">
                <input type="number" name="product_minimum" 
    class="ep__input--half" placeholder="Minimum" value="
    {{product.productMinimum}}">
                <label for="product_color" class="ep__label--half">Color: 
   </label>
                <label for="product_number" class="ep__label--half">Number: 
   </label>
                <input type="text" name="product_color" class="ep__input-- 
    half" placeholder="Color" value="{{product.productColor}}">
                <input type="number" name="product_number" 
    class="ep__input--half" placeholder="Minimum" value=" . 
    {{product.productNumber}}">
                <button class="ep__save" type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>
            </div>

</pre>
```

Comment: Is the code above to add a new item? If so, you probably want to save the item, then redirect the browser to a page where they can choose to add another item, view all previously added items, or go to a print page for this one item. If they go to the print route, then the server should generate printable html and send that to the browser. It should happen on a separate page.

Comment: The above code is a page to which a single product's properties can be edited. On that page, a QR code is generated at the bottom of the page, which links to the current page (window.location.href). I sort of get what you're saying, though I'd like to avoid saving the QR codes in the database. If you could give me some tips on how I could make that QR code invisible on this page and create a button that'll open that QR code in a separate window, I'm sure I could figure out how to use pdf.js to create what I'm looking for. I'm in over my head :(

Comment: I have this: https://monosnap.com/file/fPL0gxcec8Sx3FkhpOJW23h5S3QHU8

I'm basically looking for this: https://monosnap.com/file/nUMgCHgDUeXLGGD139IRX1HNnJOzF5

Answer (score 0):

Typing here for more space:

Assuming you have access to the Express server, why can't you create a route that retrieves all products, and for each unique product, generates a little html that includes name, id, price, and QR code? Then express can compile all the HTML and send it to the browser.

```
app.get('/products/print_stickers', function(req, res, next){

    // below is psuedo code
    var products_array = database.getAllProductInfo(); 

    res.render('print_page', { 
        products: products_array // pass data to mustahce template
    });
})
```

Then in your print_page mustache file, you just loop over information we got from the server. If it contains data for all the products, then we can create the html stickers for every product on just one page!

```
var sticker_html = `
    <ul>
        {{#.}}
            <li>
                <div class="left_side">
                    ${new QRCode("output", {
                        text: 'http://mywebsite/product/id/{{product_id}}', // using {{ mustache }} to insert product id
                        width: 256,
                        height: 256,
                        colorDark : "#04243c",
                        colorLight : "#FFFFFF",
                        correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
                    })}
                </div>
                <div class="right_side">
                    <p>{{name}}</p>
                    <p>{{date}}</p>  // using {{ mustache }} to insert product information 
                    <p>{{price}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        {{/.}}
    </ul>;
`;
Mustache.render(tmp, products_array);
```

So at this point, you'd go to this page, and the server would get the products, generate html for each unique item, send it to your browser, you print it, then use scissors to cut them up and post them where you need them. If you need to just print a single sticker, you can use an optional query param with the ID of the product, and say `if product_id, then only get 1 product from DB, generate sticker html as normal`.